# Merge videos with different resolutions

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mpmovieplayer

How to merge any two videos taken from different iOS devices.
Suppose video_1 with iPhone 4S, video_2 with an iPhone 5 and video_3 with iPad 2 or (any other ipad variations). How to merge these videos with iOS AVFoundation library or any other 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Merge means what? appending or something else?

Comment: look here [link1][1]

and here [link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382605/merging-nsdata-video-files-into-one-video-file
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757423/ios-video-editing-is-it-possible-to-merge-side-by-side-not-one-after-other-t

Comment: Yes appending one after the other. I have already gone through the links and there is no use if I have different videos from different devices.

Comment: Have you tried converting the audio's first to a common format and common bitrate etc.. and than tried again.. else look at this link it explains how to append 2 videos with same format http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios